# Reacting to a certain user with a discord bot in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to create a discord bot which has the goal to react with the dog emoji for a certain user.
I wrote this function but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea to correct the problem?

Thank you all!

```
@client.event
async def dog_react(message,author,id):
  emoji=""
  if message.author.id==xxxxx:
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    return
  return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    emoji = ""
    if ctx.author.id == xxxxx:
        await ctx.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Highly suggest checking out the Discord.py [FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html)